# Update the Datagrid Column Header properties through styles

Tags: wpf, styles

In my application i need to change the properties related to a datagrid header like ColumnHeader Font, fontsize etc. As there is no single property for the same currently, i am updating this through Style setters. But the problem is for a single property change(like FontSize) i have to create an entire collection of the SetterBase and update the single property along with the other propertied in the setterbase collection. Is there any other way to update a property as in this scenario.

Code snippet:

```
set
{
Style m_ColumnHeaderStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
m_ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(m_ColumnFontWeightProperty);
m_ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(m_ColumnFontSizeProperty);
m_ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(m_ColumnFontItalicProperty);
m_ColumnFont = new Setter(DataGridColumnHeader.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily(value));
m_ColumnHeaderStyle.Setters.Add(m_ColumnFont);
this.MyDataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle = m_ColumnHeaderStyle;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Styles in wpf have the ability to update attached values so you can declare styles in xaml once:

```
 <DataGrid >
        <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{Binding HeaderFont}"/>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

The magic happens in Binding and there are few kinds of it.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private FontFamily _headerFont;

    public FontFamily HeaderFont
    {
        get
        {
            return _headerFont;
        }
        set
        {
            _headerFont = value;

            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("HeaderFont"));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }
}
```

It is imperative that PropertyChanged event is fired when property changes.

Comment: Thanks, but i had to change the <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding HeaderFontSize}"/> as <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ElementName=window, Path=TitleFontSize}" /> . Do you know why this behaviour?

Comment: In my example i use `DataContext = this;` to set DataContext - the default object that all bindings point to. In your binding you explicitly point to visual tree element named window, which is also correct. That is one of many usages of this powerful feature.

Comment: it didn't work when i used DATACONTEXT=THIS. later we used Window as element for binding.